# Chrome flash on transition triggered by jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions, addclass

I am trying to fade in/out a background image on scroll.

I am using jQuery `.addClass()/.removeClass()` to trigger the event and CSS3 to change the opacity of the second background.

**I would like to stick to CSS3 for the animation** but there is a **white flash** when the animation is triggered on chrome.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/4DhLE/)**

**Is there a way to prevent this flash?**

*HTML :*

```
<div class="second_bg"></div>
```

*CSS :*

```
body, html {
    height:150%;
    margin:0;
}
body {
    background: url("http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-g-640-480-9.jpg") repeat scroll 0 0;
}
.second_bg {
    opacity:0;
    height:100%;
    background:#566c75;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in;
    -webkit- transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in;
}
.fade-blue {
    opacity:1;
}
```

*jQuery :*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 20) {
            $(".second_bg").addClass("fade-blue");
        } else {
            $(".second_bg").removeClass("fade-blue");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The few tricks below can help to prevent flickering — simply apply them to the `<body>` element:

- `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` [<kbd>See demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/4DhLE/10/)
- `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0)` [<kbd>See demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/4DhLE/11/)

It has worked without an issue for me, but for some reason when I test them out in your Fiddle, the properties seem to give problems when scrolling within an iframe — so you should be cautious when using this fix for production releases, or at least test them first.

p/s: Tested on a local machine, worked for me.

Comment: hey @Terry, you second demo works fine but the on the first one, the first time the animation is launched, it doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4DhLE/8/)
To fix this, you can add this in the css (`body`):

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4DhLE/5/)

Use this method instead:

```
<div class="second_bg"></div>
```

Keep the html the same.

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 20) {
            $(".second_bg").fadeIn();
        } else {
            $(".second_bg").fadeOut();
        }
    });
});
```

Change this css class to:

```
.second_bg {
    display:none;
    height:100%;
    background:#566c75;
}
```

Instead of adding and removing a class, have it always have the background position, just with `display:none;`.

Then, you can `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` to get the effect you want instead.

Comment: Thx for your answer but I would like to stick to CSS3 for the animation, this technique uses jQuery to fade the element in.

Comment: Ah I did read that in honesty, I just thought it was a preference rather than it needed to be like that. I'll keep looking at a css fix @web-tiki

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want to keep to css? @web-tiki

Comment: I am trying to stick to CSS3 because it is supposed to be faster see here : http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/blog/jquery-vs-css3-transitions/ Saw your update, the flash doesn't appear anymore but the first fade isn't animated anymore, I'm getting comfused...

Comment: It is still animated, do it a few times @web-tiki

Comment: Your last fiddle works fine, Thx for taking time to answer. I have to accept Terry's answer because he was the first to introduce these tricks.

Comment: No worries! I'm glad you got an answer! :) @web-tiki

Answer (score 1):

Adding `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` to the `body`, which enables hardware acceleration seems to work.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4DhLE/7/)**